# 2D Rotation of CALayer with UIBezierPath

Tags: objective-c, rotation, calayer, uibezierpath

I'm trying to rotate a CALayer which is composed of UIBezierPath. The display is great.

```
CALayer* layer = [CALayer layer];
CAShapeLayer *shapeView = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
UIBezierPath *arc = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[arc moveToPoint:CGPointMake(center.x + obj1.startx * cos(obj1.angle), center.y + obj1.starty * cos(obj1.angle))];
[shapeView setPath:arc.CGPath];
[layer addSublayer:shapeView];

// Rotation
layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angle, 0, 0, 1);
```

But the CATransform3DmakeRotation rotate the CAShape around the point (0,0) I guess.

I tried to set the anchorPoint to the center of the view but it's not working better.

It seems that the CAlayer has no content because its height and width are equal to zero.

What did I do wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: please post your code

Comment: The layer needs a size, as you've said. The bounding box of the path is a good choice.